# App engine standard and automatic error logging question (and also regarding Error reporting)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-logging

I am doing my first App engine project using App engine standard and Nodejs. I like the experience but I am having issues right now with error logging.

It seems that App engine logs every application error automatically with "ERROR" severity.

Is there a way to prevent App Engine standard to automatically log application errors?

I also realized that the errors that I log with @google-cloud/logging Nodejs package from App Engine standard are not added to Error reporting. Only the errors automatically logged by App Engine are. Is there a way to add those logs to Error reporting?

Thank you!

Here are some code snippets if it can help you answer or discuss this topic:

```
throw new AppCustomError({isPublic:"public",logSeverity:"WARNING",statusCode:403,errorCode:10010,dataToLog:req.dataToLog,
            message:"GETtextsData - User is not logged in."});
```

---

```
class AppCustomError extends Error{ //appCustomError is a custom Error class

constructor(errorObject){
    super();
    this.message=errorObject.message;
    this.errorCode=errorObject.errorCode; 
    this.statusCode=errorObject.statusCode;
    this.status=errorObject.statusCode >= 400 && errorObject.statusCode < 500 ? "fail" : "error";
    this.logSeverity=errorObject.logSeverity;
    this.dataToLog=errorObject.dataToLog;

    if(errorObject.isPublic==="public"){
        this.isPublic=true;
    }else{
        this.isPublic=false;
    }

    Error.captureStackTrace(this,this.connector);
}}export default AppCustomError;
```

Where the log is created using logSync() method:

```
if(process.env.GAE_APPLICATION){
env="gae";
logPayload.LOGGERenv=env;
log=logging.logSync(logName); //Using logsync will use a logging agent and stdout the log. Parameters will be set automatically. This is best for serverless applications like GAE. https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/logging/latest#writing-to-stdout
metadata.GAE_deployment_id=process.env.GAE_DEPLOYMENT_ID,
metadata.GAE_instance_id=process.env.GAE_INSTANCE,
metadata.GAE_runtime=process.env.GAE_RUNTIME}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**App Engine logs errors automatically:** You can't prevent this, but you can control your custom error logging.

You may try these steps:

- **Use `@google-cloud/logging` for structured logs**: Create clear messages, severity levels, and relevant data.
- **Optional Error Reporting integration**: Use `@google-cloud/error-reporting` to report errors explicitly for centralized management.

```
//JavaScript Example:

const { Reporting } = require('@google-cloud/error-reporting');

const errorsClient = new Reporting({
  projectId: 'your-project-id',
  // Other client options
});

// ... (Your application logic)

try {
  // Your code
} catch (error) {
  errorsClient.reportError(error);
  throw error; // Re-throw to trigger App Engine's automatic logging
}
```

- **Throw the error after logging**: Re-throw the error to trigger App Engine's automatic logging for comprehensive coverage.

Reference Documentation:

- [Google Cloud Node.js Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries)
- [Google Cloud Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/reference/libraries)
- [App Engine Standard Environment for Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! This is very good info! I did not know about @google-cloud/error-reporting. I will try this out and mark as answer soon. I am not sure why you throw the error at the end if it is already logged and reported. Can you please explain why?

Comment: Also, I just realized that the error was logged in an ugly way (many info lines) to the console because I forgot to remove a console.log(error) line of code. I will edit my question to make this clear. My mistake! Now it is not even automatically logged because I am catching it with middleware!